# web platform installer and sql server enterprise

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, enterprise, phpbb, web-platform-installer

i tied to install phpbb forum from web platform installer

all dependencies installed but when i was needed to config sql server for forum, it asked me for instance name, but i saw that my sql server enterprise edition hasn't instance name

so i a bit confused and don't know what to do :(

is anybody tried to install phpbb wit sql server enterprise edition?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed your SQL Server Enterprise without an instance, then you should just use the machine name.

EDIT: "SQL DatabaseServer Instance" shouldn't be a required parameter or should at least allow an empty string. For now, you can get away by specifying a whitespace for it. I did and it installed for me.

Comment: but web platform installer require instance name :(

Comment: You are right, they shouldn't be asking for instance name. I'll make sure the Web PI team gets a bug filed :) For a solution, see an edit.